# ActionScript game loop not running

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm developing a Flash game using ActionScript 3 and have this code in my documents class:

```
package com {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Engine extends MovieClip {
        public function Engine() {
            // Create a player instance
            var player:Player = new Player();
            addChild(player);

            // Start the game loop
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.gameLoop);
        }

        public function gameLoop(event:Event) {
            trace("hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the game, however, I don't get any output and instead get this error message:

```
C:\Users\MyName\Dropbox\Uni\DAT104\flash\com\Engine.as, Line 15 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.
```

Is there a library or something I need to import to get this to work? If it's not obvious, I want to run the `gameLoop` method of my `Engine` class (the documents class) on every new frame (the document is currently set to 30fps).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using 'gameLoop' instead of 'this.gameLoop'? also, gameLoop should be private unless you plan on having something else call that method.

Answer (score 2):

Flash is probably just complaining because it doesn't know where to find the Event class. If you add an `import flash.events.Event;` statement after the other import statements in your code, it should work.

Comment: Knew it would be something like that :) Thanks!